# Google Books API передает не все книги

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, google-books

пишу приложение по поиску книг с использованием Google Books API. Столкнулся с проблемой, что сервер в конечном итоге отправляет не все книги при дополнительной загрузке по принципу "load more". То есть, в итоговом массиве в приложении книг меньше чем сервер сообщает в момент первого запроса в поле `totalItems`. И не могу понять это в моем коде ошибка или это такое странное поведение Google Books API. Может кто сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой?

apiConfig с логикой запроса:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
export const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyClgTthPOW8evajugq_vxS3U_Gf3V-IvT1';
export const MAX_RESULTS = 30;

export const loadData = async ({
  search = '',
  category = '',
  sort = 'relevance',
  page = 0,
}) => {
  const selectedCategory = category === 'all' ? '' : category;
  const startIndex = page * MAX_RESULTS;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_URL}?q=${search}+subject:${selectedCategory}&orderBy=${sort}&startIndex=${startIndex}&maxResults=${MAX_RESULTS}&key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
```

Redux срез:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { MAX_RESULTS } from '../../apiConfig';

export const loadBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  '@@books/loadBooks',
  async ({ search, category, sort }, { extra: api }) => {
    const response = await api.loadData({ search, category, sort });
    return response;
  }
);

export const loadMoreBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  '@@books/loadMoreBooks',
  async ({ search, category, sort, page }, { extra: api }) => {
    const response = await api.loadData({ search, category, sort, page });
    return response;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  loading: 'idle', // pending / succeeded  / failed
  loadingButton: false,
  entities: [],
  total: null,
  page: 0,
  error: null,
};

export const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name: '@@books',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    clearBooks: () => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadBooks.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = 'pending';
        state.entities = [];
        state.total = null;
        state.page = 0;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loadBooks.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = 'succeeded';
        state.entities = action.payload.items;
        state.total = action.payload.totalItems;
        state.page = state.page + 1;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loadBooks.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = 'failed';
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(loadMoreBooks.pending, (state) => {
        state.loadingButton = true;
      })
      .addCase(loadMoreBooks.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.entities = state.entities.concat(action.payload.items || []);
        state.page = state.page + 1;
        state.loadingButton = false;
      })
      .addCase(loadMoreBooks.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.error.message;
        state.loadingButton = false;
      });
  },
});

export const { setError, clearBooks } = booksSlice.actions;
export const booksReducer = booksSlice.reducer;

// selectors
export const selectBooksAllInfo = (state) => state.books;
export const selectBooks = (state) => state.books.entities;
export const selectError = (state) => state.books.error;
```

Баттон Load More:

```
        <LoadingButton
          variant="contained"
          loading={loadingButton}
          onClick={() =>
            dispatch(loadMoreBooks({ search, category, sort, page }))
          }
        >
          More books
        </LoadingButton>
```

Хочу сделать чтобы эта кнопка не рендерилась если например число оставшихся книг на сервере меньше или равно нулю:

```
const remainingBooksForLoad = total - entities?.length;
```